# SQL dynamic parameterized where field and value

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

I have a stored procedure with a filter.

```
SELECT * FROM OrderBatch WHERE <field> LIKE '%pattern%';
```

However, I want the where clause to be dynamic. Idealy it would look like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetOrderBatchesFiltered]
    @filterField VARCHAR(50) = 'Delivery Address',
    @filterValue VARCHAR(300)  = '%%'
AS
    SELECT * FROM OrderBatch WHERE @filterField LIKE @filterValue;
GO
```

Two problems with this:

1. `@filterField` is not an exact column name as it's passed in from the presentation layer so I have to map it's value to the right column (sometimes even a calculated value). Even if it was an exact column name, I don't think that syntactically works.
2. The `@filterValue` might have to be in different formats depending on the `@filterField`. So sometimes I need to convert it to a DATETIME or something like that. This also means that, for some columns, I can't use the `LIKE` keyword, I have to use `=` (i.e. if it's a DATETIME).

I've looked all over online and found a lot of scenareos for using case statements but I never could get it to work with my scenareo. They all only applied to the value. So I tried applying it to mine with the column as well:

```
CASE WHEN @filterField='Full Address' THEN [OrderItem].[ADDRESS] END LIKE @filterValue,
CASE WHEN @filterField='Delivery Contact Phone' THEN [Customer].[Delivery_Contact_Phone] END LIKE @filterValue
```

But nothing seems to work. Everything I try fails to compile at the very first case statement.

So:

How do I allow the `@filterField` to specify the column to be used and the conversion of `@filterValue`?

Comment: The given requirement can be satisfied through dynamic sql, since your are trying to dynamically providing the column name. What is the dbms version you are using.

Comment: I'm using MSSQL.

Comment: [This](http://sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) is a big read, but it's worth your time.

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamic SQL commands using EXEC

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetOrderBatchesFiltered]
    @filterField VARCHAR(50) = 'Delivery Address',
    @filterValue VARCHAR(300)  = '%%'
AS
    DECLARE @sqlCommand varchar(1000)
    SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT * FROM OrderBatch WHERE ' + @filterField  + ' like ' + @filterValue
    EXEC (@sqlCommand)
GO
```